# What does $\mathbb{C}^*$ typically denote?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

What does $\mathbb{C}^*$ typically denote?

Is it the complex plane without 0?

Edit: this is in the context of the statement that tori are copies of $(\mathbb{C}^*)^n$.

Comment: I usually use $\mathbf{C}^\times$ for the complex plane without zero.

Comment: It probably depends on the context, whether it's just the set of nonzero complex numbers, or more specifically the group with $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ as its underlying set of elements, with the group operation being multiplication.

Comment: Or the topological group with the group part being as specified before, and the topology part being the subspace topology.  Or possibly just the topological space / differential manifold / complex manifold / Lie group.  Etc. etc.

Comment: What is the definition of a torus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, it depends on the context. To complex analysts the notation $\Bbb{C}^*$ usually mean the punctured plane $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ whereas to algebraists, it usually mean the multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers.

Comment: There is no such a field: It denotes the multiplicative group.

Comment: Yes you're right!